# Performance optimization: Alternative to LEFT JOIN the same table twice

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, optimization

I would like to extend the following query with the commented out LEFT JOIN. However, those lines make the query noticeably slower.
The query is used for an API to lookup user IDs by phone number and things need to be fast. So, is there a more performant alternative to joining the same table twice with different ON clauses?

```
set statistics time on 

SELECT
    ivr.ID
FROM ivr
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDR_MASTER am1
    ON am1.ID = ivr.ID
        AND am1.ADDR_TYPE = 'WORK' --WORK PHONE (only adds 35ms to lookup time)
--LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDR_MASTER am2
--  ON am2.ID = ivr.ID
--      AND am2.ADDR_TYPE = 'HOME' --HOME PHONE (fallback if not in IVR, adds 100+ ms :(
WHERE (PHONE1 = '0123456789'
OR PHONE2 = '0123456789'
OR PHONE3 = '0123456789'
OR am1.PHONE = '0123456789'
--OR am2.PHONE = '0123456789'
)

set statistics time off
```

Here are the plans:

- [Old](https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkbpt0oPS)
- [New](https://brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJoKcRsvSDelete)

Comment: [Getting Help With A Slow Query](https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2009/03/getting-help-with-a-slow-query/)

Comment: In your current query, there is no need for a join because you aren't returning anything from those tables, and it's a LEFT join.Have you simplified the query?

Comment: Which table(s) have `phone1` - `phone3`?

Comment: I noticed you have `OR am1.PHONE = '0123456789'` in your where clause. This changes your join to an `INNER`. I also presume the phone1,2,3 are in your ivr since you should get an ambiguous column error otherwise.

Comment: Yes, phone1,2,3 are on the IVR table.
Here are the plans: Old https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=Bkbpt0oPS
and new https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=SJoKcRsvS

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will do what you are asking.

```
SELECT
    ivr.ID
FROM ivr
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDR_MASTER am1
    ON am1.ID = ivr.ID
        AND am1.ADDR_TYPE IN ('WORK','HOME')
WHERE (PHONE1 = '0123456789'
OR PHONE2 = '0123456789'
OR PHONE3 = '0123456789'
OR am1.PHONE = '0123456789'
)
```

That said, there are a few things you could do differently.

This might be better, not sure, but as long as it's not slower it's probably easier to maintain.

```
SELECT
    ivr.ID
FROM ivr
LEFT OUTER JOIN ADDR_MASTER am1
    ON am1.ID = ivr.ID
        AND am1.ADDR_TYPE IN ('WORK','HOME')
WHERE '0123456789' IN (PHONE1, PHONE2, PHONE3, am1.PHONE)
```

Now, assuming that you do in fact only need the ivr.ID (at least not anything from ADDR_MASTER) you could do this:

```
SELECT
    ivr.ID
FROM ivr
WHERE '0123456789' IN (PHONE1, PHONE2, PHONE3)
    OR EXISTS ( SELECT 1 FROM ADDR_MASTER am1
                WHERE am1.ID = ivr.ID
                    AND am1.ADDR_TYPE IN ('WORK','HOME')
                    AND am1.PHONE = '0123456789' )
```

I'd try various combinations to see which if any of these are actually faster.

Comment: Thank you very much, Kenneth. The first suggestion is basically the same as the original but with the added join/conditions. The second, however, is even fast and down to 15 ms. Love it!

Answer (score 1):

Refactoring the table would be easier. Phone numbers should be in a separate, related table, not in the addresses table (as shown by the need for multiple phone fields), something like this (simplified as an example - flags for FAX machines, cellphone, Peferred #, always an answering machine, no calls after 6pm, etc may be needed as well):

```
CREATE TABLE PhoneNumbers (
    PhoneId bigint IDENTITY(1,1),
    AddrId bigint NOT NULL,
    PhoneNo varchar(20) NOT NULL,
    -- PK assumes this will most often pull up phone numbers for a given address
    CONSTRAINT PK_PhoneNumbers_AddrID_PhoneID (AddrId, PhoneId) 
    )

CREATE UNIQUE INDEX Idx_PhoneNumbers_PhoneNo_INCLUDE
ON PhoneNumbers (PhoneNo) INCLUDE (AddrId) -- Look up Addr by Phone # index
```

When you want all of the phones associated with an address, go in by AddrId. When you want all of the addresses associated with a phone number, go in by phone number.  And the number of phones associated with an address is effectively unlimited, rather than limited to the number of columns designated for the purpose.

Comment: Thank you for your reasonable advice and your explanations. Unfortunately, this is basically a 3rd-Party database and we cannot make certain changes, like refactoring standard tables.